# 特定のキーが入力されるまで文字を読み込み続ける処理を書きたい。

Tags: c#

定義コードの「ここ」部分なのですがそこに特定のキーではない場合ループを続けるといって処理を書きたくて実装に困っています
C言語の入門問題である[getchar()がEOFじゃないとき無限に文字を入力し続けるプログラム]
のC#版を書きたくて困っています。

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.ConsoleKeyInfo c;

            c = Console.ReadKey();

            while ( c != ConsoleKey.F1)//ここ
            {
                //char x = (char)Console.ReadKey().Key;

                //Console.WriteLine(x);
            }


            Console.WriteLine("end");



            Console.ReadKey();
        }              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんなかんじでいかがでしょうか

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var c = Console.ReadKey();
            if (c.Key == ConsoleKey.F1)
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(c.KeyChar);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("end");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```